# passing variable into SELECT clause with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is my **model**, which works when I query one table only:

```
function cari_username()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $this->db->like('username',$username);
        $data = $this->db->get('user');
        return $data;
    }
```

What I need is to join data from several tables, but now my code fails:

```
function cari_username()
    {
        $this->db->from('user');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT user.id_user,mahasiswa.nama,user.password,user.username 
           FROM (`mahasiswa`) 
           LEFT JOIN `pendaftaran_anggota` ON `pendaftaran_anggota`.`nim` = `mahasiswa`.`nim`
           LEFT JOIN `anggota` ON `pendaftaran_anggota`.`id_anggota` = `anggota`.`id_anggota` 
           LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id_user` = `anggota`.`id_user` UNION 
           SELECT pelatih.id_user, pelatih.nama,user.password,user.username FROM (`pelatih`)
           LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id_user` = `pelatih`.`id_user` UNION 
           SELECT admin.id_user, admin.nama, user.password,user.username FROM (`admin`)
           LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id_user` = `admin`.`id_user`) userdata WHERE `username` LIKE username
            ORDER BY `userdata`.`id_user`
             ");

        return $data;
    }
```

Please tell me how to change the query to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: By like Username do you mean equals. Only guessing as I haven;t used CodeIgniter but if db->like is putting wild cards in as in Like '%Smith%' your query is not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your script:

first:

`WHERE username LIKE username` will not work, as username like any php variable should be `$username`

second:

mysql doesn't know which kind of variable $username is, but we know it's a string. Therefore you need to place it within single quotes:

```
WHERE `username` LIKE '$username'
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understood you right to be honest: So your Selection from the admin-table by username is not working?

Well I guess it should be `username LIKE $username`. So you forgot the $.

```
LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id_user` = `admin`.`id_user` userdata WHERE `username` LIKE $username ORDER BY `userdata`.`id_user`
```

Comment: thank you. i try like this and example i search username "rian" and than the result database error because Unknown column 'rian' in 'where clause'. how about that?

Comment: yes i want to selection name from admin-table by username to user-table.

Comment: Be sure your query looks like the one i posted in the post above. (I just edited my post)
It looks like you use the variable-value also for defining the column which shall be used for selection, which would be wrong.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT user.id_user,mahasiswa.nama,user.password,user.username FROM  LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id_user` = `admin`.`id_user`) userdata WHERE `username` LIKE rian ORDER BY `userdata`.`id_user`

Comment: Unknown column 'rian' in 'where clause'

Comment: Is userdata another table? If so seperate the sub-select and this one by ",". Use ' around strings (in this case: `LIKE 'rian'`). Make sure the column username is defined in a table. You might consider using the "as"-statement to access field of your subselection like
`<subselect> as ss WHERE ss.username LIKE $username`

Comment: its become userdata WHERE `userdata.username` LIKE $username? but it still error

Comment: error its still same Unknown column 'rian' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this ->db -> query("select * from tablename where fname ='$string'");
```

Don't forget to pass the `$string` in the function where the model is created.